# Is there a way to make image file previews bigger than 256 (extra large) in Windows 10?

Tags: windows-explorer, thumbnails

I bought myself a bigger monitor with 2560x1440px resolution and I want the image previews to be biiiig but they seem to be limited to 256px size at "extra large" setting. Fullscreen at max size it fits 9x5 files.

I tried changing the DPI setting from 100% to 200% and it doesn't change the max size of image file previews, only all buttons and texts get bigger.

[There was advice](https://www.technipages.com/windows-change-image-thumbnail-size) about adding thumbnail size value to registry key `Computer\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer` dword "ThumbnailSize" and it didn't work with 512 (hex 100).

Is there a working way to increase max preview size in explorer for a modern Windows 10 version (1809) or should I look for an image gallery browser app? I really like the convenience of having all the default Windows Explorer hotkeys and controls though, but if there's no native way then I'll consider third-party apps.